# Accessing Kibana of AWS ElasticSearch by Gateway using AWS IAM

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-iam, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm studying about ELK Stack and AWS Gateway.

I created AWS ElasticSearch and set this access policy:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::[AWS account ID]:root"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:sa-east-1:[AWS account ID]:domain/camarar-elk/*"
    }
  ]
}

PS: I try to use with this policy too:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
       "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::[AWS account ID]:user/[User]"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:sa-east-1:[AWS account ID]:domain/camarar-elk/*"
    }
  ]
}

After, I created an AWS API Gateway using http proxy and GET method to route all request to Kibana url. And in this Gateway I using one AWS IAM to access Kibana.

Finally, I created an user of AWS IAM with this policy "AmazonESFullAccess".

All the time I received the same error:{"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet on resource: camarar-elk"}

Anybody could you please help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: You can also use a proxy service such as https://www,iamproxy.com Disclosure: I am the author of this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm already using a policy with this action("Action": "es:*") because I wrote wrong in my question.

My actual policy in Elasticsearch:

{ "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Effect": "Allow", "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::[AWS account ID]:root" }, "Action": "es:*", "Resource": "arn:aws:es:sa-east-1:[AWS account ID]:domain/camarar-elk/*" } ] }

Answer (score 0):

> "Action": "es:",

I believe this is your problem. You'll have to either specify an action like es:ESHttpGet or allow all actions with es:*